# How do some calculations in branch-and-bound for quadratic assignment problem work?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization, quadratic-programming

I am currently trying to implement a branch-and-bound approach to solve the quadratic assignment problem by following the paper 'A parallel branch and bound algorithm for the quadratic assignment problem' which can be found here: [Link to paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X87900229). I got quite far already, but I am missing some information. Maybe someone can help me understand the last steps.

My problem mainly focuses on understanding page 7 (page 217 in the corner). So, on the first node, I calculate the lower and upper bound. Then I create new nodes (in this case $T_1,\dots,T_3$ and save them in a list. With the permutation $p^{B^0}$ I can calculate the cost of the branch $T_3$. Now the algorithm jumps to the next node $T_2$ saved in the list. The permutation for this node is not finished yet. As I understand it, I have to find a partial permutation $\beta$, that completes this branch. Can I choose an arbitrary $\beta$ here? If so, what happens if there are a lot of prohibited assignments already. Is there an elegant way to find a suitable $\beta$, that is programmable?

After finding $\beta$, is the instruction for finding $B^{(k)}(\beta)$ an update instruction to the previously found $B$, returning a new $B$ of size $n\times n$ or does this return a smaller matrix?

I hope my questions are clear enough. If not, feel free to ask more. I really need to get this algorithm implemented as soon as possible.

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. A link to the paper you're referencing would help readers understand better. You can edit your post to add that info.

Comment: Thank you :)
Thanks for the hint, I updated the post with a link to the paper!